# Android Studio Cannot resolve error after blue screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Android Studio started showing error after pc got blue screen and restarted. It is showing 'Cannot resolve' for all the classes. I re installed android studio as well as JDK but still it shows the same error. Not getting the problem.Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to sync Android Studio with gradle files (Tools -> Android -> Sync Project Files With Gradle).

When it does not help, close Android Studio, delete .idea folder and *.iml file in your project root directory. Then open Android Studio and import project again.

I hope it will help.